# fetch child models polymorphic associations from parent model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Category model that is connected to 2 other models `Listing` & `Group` through the `has_many` association.

```
class `Category` < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :listings
   has_many :groups
end
```

**Listing**

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :Category
 has_many :user_items, as: :itemable
end
```

**Group**

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :Category
 has_many :user_items, as: :itemable
end
```

There is another model which can either be of type listing/group(polymorphic)

**UserItem**

```
class UserItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :itemable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Everything works fine. But how can I access all `user_items` from `category`?

I tried like below

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :listings
   has_many :groups
   #Below will work but only fetches the user items of listing type.
   has_many :user_items, through: :listings
   #How can I fetch both types here
   #has_many :user_items, through: [:listings, :groups] #something like this???
end
```

So I can call like `category.user_items`

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```rb
  def user_items(reload=false)
    @user_items = nil if reload
    @user_items ||= UserItem.where("(itemable_type = ? AND itemable_id IN (?)) OR
                            (itemable_type = ? AND itemable_id IN (?))", 
                           "Listing", listing_ids, "Group", group_ids)
  end
```

Comment: Tried that. But getting error `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError (Can't join 'UserItem' to association named 'listing'; perhaps you misspelled it?)`

Comment: @Abhilash sorry for the delay, I just edited my answer. Can you please check if it is acceptable answer for your case?